# Count each product orders in product listing with one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

there are 2 tables in mysql db:

```
products: id, ...
products_order: id, pid,
                     ^
                 products.id
```

In a product listing page how to show each products' orders (for example this product is ordered by 4 people) without having a query for each product.
for example

```
select count(*) from products_order where pid = 1
```

Getting the result like this:

```
pid    count
 1       5
 2       12
 3       1
 4       32
...     ...
```

As there is a pagination of 20 there I've tried

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE pid IN (1,2,3,4, ... 20)
```

but it doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: Learn to use `group by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this sql

```
SELECT pid, COUNT(pid) FROM products_order GROUP BY pid;
```